# How do I create 3 separate security groups from 1 security group resource block?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Right now I have a bastion host in 3 separate public subnets and they all share the same security group. However, I would like to create 3 separate security groups, one for each bastion host that gets created. I have 1 resource block that creates 3 bastion hosts total (1 for each subnet), is there any way I can create a separate security group for each of them. utilizing just one security group resource block?

**bastion.tf**

```
resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  count           = var.azs
  ami             = data.aws_ami.AL2_ami.id
  key_name        = aws_key_pair.bastion_auth.id
  instance_type   = var.instance_type
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.bastion-sg.id]

  associate_public_ip_address = true
  subnet_id                   = module.vpc.public_subnets[count.index]
  user_data                   = file("userdata.tpl")

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = var.main_vol_size
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}-bastion-host-${count.index + 1}"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "bastion-sg" {

  name   = "bastion-security-group"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = -1
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Error after making changes:

```
Error: expected metadata_options.0.instance_metadata_tags to be one of [disabled enabled], got coalfire-bastion-1
│
│   on node-group.tf line 40, in resource "aws_security_group" "node-sg":
│   40:     security_groups = [aws_security_group.bastion-sg.id]
│
│ Because aws_security_group.bastion-sg has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     aws_security_group.bastion-sg[count.index]
```

Comment: Well, you could do the same for the SG, use `count`.

Comment: @MarkoE I added `count = aws_instance.bastion[count.index]` to my SG and as a tag added ` tags = {
    Name = "bastion-sg-${count + 1}"
  }`

It's giving me a Cycle error between the bastion instance and the bastion sg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to add the same `count = var.azs` to the security group resource as well:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "bastion-sg" {
  count  = var.azs
  name   = "bastion-security-group-${count.index}"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = -1
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

For the bastion host, you may want to use the `count.index` to refer to a security group:

```hcl
resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  count           = var.azs
  # ...
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.bastion-sg[count.index].id]
  
  # ...
}
```

This will create 3 identical security group for each bastion host. Please note, you can not have the same name for each security group. To overcome this limitation, you can add the `count.index` to the name of the SG as well.

Comment: I made the changes and I'm getting an error, I specified the new error at the bottom of my post, so it's easier to read

Comment: First of all, I have no idea why do you get `instance_metadata_tags` error. There are no such tags used in your snippet from what we can see.  Moreover, are you sure that you made the change correctly for the bastion host? (`security_groups = [aws_security_group.bastion-sg[count.index].id]`)

Comment: Apologies, I accidentally added that somewhere and removed it again and mispelled. It's all good now